# How can I create a regex for a phone number validation, that matches the number with the prefix or only the number if the prefix is not given?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to create a regex for a phone number validation. The pattern should work like that: if the user writes the prefix (with the plus symbol optional), then the phone number must follow with 4 to 14 numbers. Otherwise, when the prefix is not given, the user has to write from 4 to 14 numbers only.
The regex I wrote is that:

```
^([+]?[0-9]{1,3})([0-9]{4,14})$|^([0-9]{4,14})$
```

I've tested the regex with these strings: 
3333333333 --> works 
+393333333333 --> works 
+39333 --> works but it shouldn't. I expected to have at least four numbers after the prefix

What am I missing?

Comment: _"I expected to have at least four numbers after the prefix"_ - and that is what you got here. `+3` is the prefix - you used the quantifier `{1,3}` for the digit part of that! - and `9333` are your four digits (not "numbers") after that matched prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a regular expression you can use to validate a phone number with or without a prefix:

```
^(?:\+?\d{1,3})?\s*(\d{3})[-.\s]*(\d{3})[-.\s]*(\d{4})$
```

Here are some examples of phone numbers that would match this regular expression:

**+1 555-123-4567 |
555-123-4567 |
5551234567 |
1 555 123 4567**

Note that this regular expression assumes that the phone number has 10 digits (without the prefix) or 13 digits (with the prefix). If you need to allow for phone numbers with a different number of digits, you may need to modify the regular expression accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining "the prefix" as `[0-9]{1,3}` with a quantifier that allows backtracking

So it can also match a single digit followed by a minimum of 4 digits in the second part `[0-9]{4,14}` which matches `+39333` in total.

You could make the pattern more specific, as `[0-9]{1,3}` can match any digit 1 to 3 times and you can not tell what the (valid) prefix is.

For example making +39 optional:

```
^(?:[+]39)?[0-9]{4,14}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EOOEeV/1)